# high sys cpu and high ithr in pmap on solaris

Tags: solaris

I have a mysql database running on solaris, from mpstat, I could see a thread has very high ithr and high sys cpu. How can I find where the ithr comes from and why the sys cpu is relatively high?

CPU minf mjf xcal  intr ithr  csw icsw migr smtx  srw syscl  usr sys  wt idl

0    0   0    0   440  146  269    1   17   52    0   833    0   1   0  99
.......................................................................

7    0   0    0 19798 19738  914   22    4  242    0  3569    5  14   0  81
........................................................................

15    0   0    0  1005    0 2035    2    0   52    0  8912   12   3   0  85

CPU minf mjf xcal  intr ithr  csw icsw migr smtx  srw syscl  usr sys  wt idl

0    0   0    0   632  143  678    1   26   46    0  2243    4   2   0  94
........................................................................

7    0   0    0 21068 20978 1409   27    9  276    0  5591    9  15   0  76

.................................................................

15  0   0    0   531    0 1071    2    2   45    0  4707    7   2   0  91

---

Comment: Sorry the last sentences of your question got accidentally hashed.......   Just kidding!

Comment: Which version of solaris are you running on?  This is really a question for serverfault.com, too bad it's still in beta..

Comment: we are running on solaris 10. Looks like lots of package transferring over network will cause high ithr and high sys cpu

Answer (score 2):

That's probably a NIC's interrupt overhead.   mpstat will show high values in ithr for the CPU's handling any NICs or HBAs, and a correspondingly high sys time.  If you have Solaris 10, intrstat will show exactly how much time is spent handling hardware interrupts per CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The Sun Studio tools include a performance analyzer that is designed to take advantage of all the latest features in Solaris.  You could try using it to collect data on the mysql server.  We're getting close to the next official release, but you can use a recent "express" release to check out the latest features. It's not open source, but it's free to use. http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/downloads/express/index.jsp